# Get IP of Android for P2P connection

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming, p2p

Would it be possible to get the IP of Android Phone for P2P connection, Actually i want to connect two android Phones via Sockets ?

Comment: Over what kind of network? 3G? Both on same Wifi?

Comment: @david not on same wifi. i means on internet.
let one person is in US and other is in UK. Is it possible

Comment: If you're trying to do peer-to-peer communications between two devices that may both be behind NAT or 3G, that's a very advanced case that should not be attempted until you have significant expertise in client/server and simpler peer-to-peer cases (such as both on same Wifi).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need a central server which helps with peer discovery. That's not all even getting IP might not be enough you'll have to work around issues like Net traversal ..this may help [Android: NAT Traversal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367727/android-nat-traversal)